# How to add the tax and then multiply with the price in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add the tax and multiply the result with a total price.

Here are the tables
"Charge" Table
[image: Charge Table]

Charge_Type

[image: Charge_type]

Tax_type

[image: Tax Type]

charge type tax list

[image: Tax list by Charge type]

I want to calculate the tax and the multiply with the amount for each charge_id
I tried attempting this way:

```
SELECT  `charge_id` AS  "Charge ID", SUM( tt.percentage ) AS  "Tax"
FROM charge c, charge_type ct, tax_type tt, charge_type_tax_list cttl
WHERE tt.tax_type_id = cttl.tax_type_id
GROUP BY c.charge_type_id, c.charge_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: you should do this programmatically

Comment: What you have tried yet in query post that also ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz I have edited my post

Comment: @Himani Please help future SO readers to quickly access the correct/best answer by awarding one of the answers with a green tick.  If neither solve the issue, please leave a comment on each to explain what isn't quite right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a join syntax that was made redundant more than twenty years ago. Whichever book or class or tutorial has been teaching you this outdated syntax, quit it. This syntax is prone to errors, as your own query plainly shows. Your query translated to proper joins is:

```
SELECT  `charge_id` AS  "Charge ID", SUM( tt.percentage ) AS  "Tax"
FROM charge c
CROSS JOIN charge_type ct
CROSS JOIN tax_type tt
INNER JOIN charge_type_tax_list cttl ON tt.tax_type_id = cttl.tax_type_id
GROUP BY c.charge_type_id, c.charge_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

You are combining all charge records with all charge_type records and all tax_type records. 6 x 3 x 3 = 54 records in your example. This makes no sense. You would want to join only related records in the first place.

What you really want to do is join charges with their tax sum:

```
select
  c.charge_id,
  tax.tax_sum,
  c.amount,
  c.amount * (1 + coalesce(tax.tax_sum, 0)) as taxed_amount
from charge c
left join
(
  select
    cttl.charge_type_id,
    sum(tt.percentage) as tax_sum
  from charge_type_tax_list cttl
  join tax_type tt on tt.tax_type_id = cttl.tax_type_id
  group by cttl.charge_type_id
) tax on tax.charge_type_id = c.charge_type_id;
```

Comment: I have run your query but it does not output a result for each of the charges

Comment: This would be the case when there is no tax for a charge. I've updated my answer so the query outer-joins the taxes now.

Answer (score 1):

You could do an `INNER JOIN` between the tables and calculate the corresponding `percentage`'s grouped by charge `id`. The query below should do the trick:

```
SELECT charge.charge_type_id, (SUM(percentage) + 1) * charge.amount AS total_tax
FROM charge INNER JOIN charge_type ON charge.charge_type_id = charge_type.charge_type_id 
INNER JOIN charge_type_tax_list ON charge_type.id = charge_type_tax_list.charge_type_id 
INNER JOIN tax_type ON charge_type_tax_list.tax_type_id = tax_type.tax_type_id GROUP BY charges.id;
```